# Unable to access service running inside AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, kubernetes

I have a kubernetes cluster having a master and two minions.

I have a service running using the public IP of one of the minion as the external IP of the service.

I have a deployment which runs a POD providing the service.Using the docker IP of the POD I am able to access the service.

But I am not able to access it using the external IP and the cluster IP.
The security groups have the necessary ports open.

Can someone help on what I am missing here.The same setup works fine in my local VM cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to access the service is to use a `NodePort`, then assuming your security groups allow that port you can access the service via the public ip of the node:nodeport assigned.

Alternately and a better approach to not expose your nodes to the public internet is to setup the CloudProvider to be type `AWS` and create a service type `LoadBalancer`, then the service will be provisioned with an ELB publicly.